# GA Behavior Flow with Grouped Pages

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics and would like to analyze site performance with behavior flows. However, our website has a lot of URLs with a constant subdirectory 1, but a changing subdirectory 2; for example:

```
www.example.com/test/abc123
www.example.com/test/bcd234
www.example.com/test/cde345
```

I would like to be able to group all of those together in my behavior flow, so that similar to the way I might see these subdirectories in my behavior flow:

```
/
/about/
/faqs/
```

I would also see:

```
/test/
```

Rather than breaking it down into hundreds of /test/ URLs. Is there any way to do this kind of grouping on the historical data? (I am also using Google Data Studio for analysis, so would be open to creating a similar report there if possible to do this type of grouping.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content grouping is not retroactive in Google Analytics therefore you cannot group historical data on the platform. Instead, you can export the data and process it.

Comment: But it's not possible to export data from a behavior flow, right? I would essentially need to use the API to import the data manually and re-create a behavior flow by hand?